# CPLEX MIP early termination with relative gap, getBestObjValue vs getObjValue

Tags: c++, optimization, cplex

I'm using C++ to model a (maximization) MIP with CPLEX, and I specify a relative gap using

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap, gap);
```

I'm puzzled by the difference between

```
cplex.getBestObjValue();
```

and

```
cplex.getObjValue();
```

in case of early termination because of the gap.

If I understand correctly, the value from `getBestObjValue()` will always correspond to an *integer* *feasible* solution, and a *lower* bound to the optimal value. On the other hand, the value from `getObjValue()` (may? will always?) correspond to a *non-feasible* solution and is an *upper* bound to the optimal value. Am I understanding this correctly?

I also have another question: the value returned by `getBestObjValue()` is, in the case of maximization problems, 'the maximum objective function value of all remaining unexplored nodes' (from the CPLEX docs). Is there a a way to query the objective values of these unexplored nodes? I'm asking because I would like to get the minimal value that satisfies my relative gap, not the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual:

> Cplex.GetBestObjValue Method: 
>   It is computed for a minimization problem as the minimum objective function value of all remaining unexplored nodes. Similarly, it is computed for a maximization problem as the maximum objective function value **of all remaining unexplored nodes**.
>   For a regular MIP optimization, this value is also the best known bound on the optimal solution value of the MIP problem. In fact, when a problem has been solved to optimality, this value matches the optimal solution value.

It corresponds to an upper bound (when maximising) of the objective value, there is a gap when you stop the solver before reaching optimality. In MIP, there is branch and bound tree behind, as more nodes are explored, the upper bound decreases. There might or might not be any solution matching the upper bound when you stop by epgap.

Therefore your assumption below is wrong:

> *If I understand correctly, the value from getBestObjValue() will always correspond to an integer feasible solution.*

GetObjValue() on the other hand is the objective value of the current best solution (corresponding to a found feasible solution). It is a lower bound, this is the value that you want to use in your second question.

Comment: Note that getObjValue() is not a lower bound as the current feasible integer solution can (and likely is) higher than the optimal one. This is in fact an upper bound.

Comment: @KyleBooth: if you read the question, you might notice that the discussion was around a **maximisation problem** vs stopping criteria **relative gap**. However, as I didn't alter the quote from Cplex manual which refers to a minimisation problem, that might have caused your confusion.
GetObjValue() corresponds to a found solution, in a maximisation problem it is a lower bound (because it might have stopped due to relative gap).